Transitive Dependency conflict .NET Core+
(I am familiar with this and this questions but they're about .NET Framework, not about .NET Core+)
Picture the following scenario:

We have a .NET 8 project with nuget dependencies A and B (referenced like <PackageReference Include="A" Version="3.33.0" />), they both depend on C.
A depends on C version 1.1
B also depends on C but version 1.2

NuGet is going to pick version 1.2 during restore, as it's the newest one.
However, version 1.2 introduced a breaking change, breaking functionality of the dependency A, making it throw all sort of exceptions during runtime, such as "Method not found".
Is there a sensible way of addressing this issue in a .NET Core+ app, without relying on the creators of A to update their dependencies?
Ideally, a way for dependency A to use version 1.1, while keeping the version on 1.2 for B and the project itself.

Not really - A 1.2 shouldn't have made those breaking changes without a major version bump, but even if they did you would still be in this predicament. You need to use a a version with the same expectations of the binary interface for the members it uses in all the projects in your dependency tree.
